# Using ¨output¨ as in ¨research output¨

Tags: word-usage

Which of the following sentences are correct ?

1. Dr. X has an amazing research output in the field of Y.
2. Dr. X has amazing research outputs in the field of Y.
3. Dr. X has amazing research output in the field of Y.

Context: Dr. X has been working in the field of Y. The results that he has obtained are amazing.

Comment: The phrase _research output_, as used in American academic contexts, refers to the **quantity** of papers and books published, not the **quality** of the research results they represent. Quantity can be counted, and therefore is. Quality is another matter.

Comment: Are we allowed to bend these sentences or must we pick one of the three?

Comment: We don't refer to "research output" in such contexts. It's just *amazing **results** in that field*.

Comment: @John Lawler. Thanks for your answer. If I wanted to refer to the quality of the research results. Can I say "Dr. X's research is amazing" or do I have to necessarily mention the word "results" like in "Dr. X's research results are amazing" ?

Comment: For quantity, "prodigious" might fit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the options you offered in your question sound correct. (1) and (3) are at least grammatically correct, but still don't make sense.

As explained in the comments, "research output" usually refers only to the number of papers published. If you want to refer to the quality of a researcher's publications, I would suggest:

#### Body of work

> [body of work - the total output of a writer or artist (or a substantial part of it)](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/body+of+work)

"Dr. X has an amazing body of work in the field of Y."

If you don't want to refer *only* to the publications, then **results** is a good choice:

- Dr. X has achieved amazing results in the field of Y.
- Dr. X's research in the field of Y has shown amazing results.

"Research results" sounds awkward and redundant to me, so I wouldn't use that particular phrase.